# Log off All users in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I want to log off all users in WordPress (all active sessions) when the site goes into maintenance. This is to prevent users from making any changes at that time.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think if you go into the `wp-config.php` file and change the Authentication Key Salts, it will force everyone to log back in again. Look for the section where it says **Authentication Unique Keys and Salts.**

This site will generate new random salts that you can replace when you're done.
https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/

Comment: @Matteo Probably not since it will screw up someone editing a post. It's just a quick way to do this. Ideally, you would use a plugin that could account for various situations, post a message to logged in users, etc.

Answer (score 2):

There's a plugin for WP called "Force ReAuthentication" implementing the functionality:
https://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/force-reauthentication/

And the source code is available on GitHub:
https://github.com/shrkey/forcereauthentication